# How to read content of a Telegram channel posts by post link?

Tags: hyperlink, telegram, telegram-bot, channel

Telegram channels posts have the post link when it is right clicked on it and in this form:
https://telegram.me/channel_name/post_ID

The question is how we can read the content of that posts (text, image, video, audio) using a bot on the server?

Comment: as @Jebediah says,  #telegram-cli, it might work for you.

Comment: @AliRasoulian; Unfortunately no. Even [telegram-cli](https://github.com/vysheng/tg) can't do it (until now = 2018, Oct.).

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to do this at the moment.

You can try using the [telegram-cli](https://github.com/vysheng/tg) (**test** branch supports channels), but it cannot find the post by its `POST_ID` — only by the full message id.