# How to get Telegram channel post with android(DrKlo) api

Tags: android, api, post, telegram, channel

I want to get channel post with post id like this https://t.me/BotNews/29

<29> is POST_ID in here . in all of the telegram official apps, when you wrote the link in the chat textbox, telegram app  convert it to hyperlink and when you click on this link, you Transferred on the channel post .so when we compile drklo api and open the application, we can see this action . it means the answer on this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888354/how-to-read-content-of-a-telegram-channel-posts-by-post-link-and-php) is Wrong !!

any one know how can we get telegram channel message(post) with POST_ID?

Answer (score 0):

there is a long story to include in an answer:
but as a starting point, you should create a request of type getHistory and call it in an other thread than UI thread:

```
TLRPC.TL_messages_getHistory req = new TLRPC.TL_messages_getHistory();
req.limit = 1;
req.offset_id = postID-1;
req.offset_date = 0;
```

Comment: thank you for good answer . but pay attention . i know how can get message with MESSAGE_ID . in here i want to get message object with POST_ID

Comment: As i mentioned before, it's a long story. But as another point to consider: Check the loadmessages function in messagescontroller.java which has implemented this functionality.

Comment: yea, i did something like this before.